# Unity no text in Game View

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, text

I have a text showing in Scene View but when I go to Game View (with play pressed or not) the next doesn't show up. What could cause that ?

[Scene View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb95a.png)

[Game View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9CH.png)

Comment: Please make a screenshot of your scene view.

Comment: I added them to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check "*Order in Layer*" at your Image. You may have set it to be above of your Order in Layer at your Canvas for text.

Comment: If I move the text in the center of the screen it still doesn't show up. And the Canvas is scaled with the camera.
The Canvas is higher than the images in the hierarchy.

Comment: edit my answer.. probably the problem lies at the order in Layer for those components ;)

Comment: In Order in Layer my Canvas is at 2, my Player at 1 and my images at 0, is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.. right now I have no clue what else could cause this.

Comment: In the worst case, just create that Text component again. There are no other reasons for it to not appear when placed at front of everything else..

Comment: Made a new Canvas and it looks like it's working... wtf

Comment: I know how you feel know. For me, that's not unexpected. I had a similar problem not far ago, where I just needed to declare the same number again because on some miracle Unity saw something else. Glad you've got it working ;)